# Independence of quotient of order statistics

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have the following problem:

> Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be three independent random variables and identically distributed with density $$f_X(x)=2x, 0<x<1$$
> Find the joint density function of $Z_1=\frac{Y_1}{Y_2}$, $Z_2=\frac{Y_2}{Y_3}$, $Z_3=Y_3$ where $Y_1<Y_2<Y_3$ are the order statistics.
> Are they independent?

My attempt:
I thought I could use the fact that if $Z$ is a quotient of random variables then $f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f_{Y_1}(zy_2)f_{Y_2}(x_2)}\,dy_2$.
So first I tried to obtain the distribution functions of $Y_i$ and then integrate and all.

But I find this process rather long and exhausting, and I don't even know if it is the right way to answer it. Is there another way to solve it?
Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well to start, that's not the ratio distribution, and the *order statistics* are not independent, so instead:$$\begin{align}f_{Z_1}(z_1) &= \int_0^1 f_{Y_1/Y_2, Y_2}(z_1, y)\,\mathrm d y \\ &= \int_0^1 \begin{Vmatrix}y & 0 \\z_1 & 1\end{Vmatrix}\, f_{Y_1,Y_2}(z_1y,y)\,\mathrm d y&&\text{using the Jacobian determinant}\\&=3!\int_0^1 y\,f_{X}(z_1y)\,f_X(y)\,(1-F_X(y))\,\mathrm d y&&\text{using order statistics}\\&=24\,\mathbf 1_{0<z_1<1}\int_0^1 z_1y^3\,(1-y^2)\,\mathrm d y&&{f_X(x)=2x\,\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}\\F_X(x)=x^2\,\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant x}}\\&=2z_1\,\mathbf 1_{0<z<1}\\[3ex]f_{Z_2}(z_2) &=\int_0^1 f_{Y_2/Y_3, Y_3}(z_2, y)\,\mathrm d y \\&=\int_0^1 y\,f_{Y_2,Y_3}(z_2y,y)\,\mathrm d y&&\text{similar, but different order statistics}\\&~~\vdots\\[3ex]f_{Z_3}(z_3) &= f_{Y_3}(z_3)&&\text{much easier}\\&= 3f_X(z_3) F_X(z_3)^2\\&= 6z_3^5\,\mathbf 1_{0<z_3<1}\end{align}$$

Next.  Checking for all combinations of **pairwise independence** will be tedious.  However, it would be unnecessary to do so should the variables be **mutually independent**, as that entails pairwise independence.

So first check that. Does: $f_{Z_1,Z_2,Z_3}(z_1,z_2,z_3) \overset?= f_{Z_1}(z_1)\,f_{Z_2}(z_2)\,f_{Z_3}(z_3)$

If that is so, then you would be done.  Otherwise you shall have to check all the pairwise combinations, at least until you find one that fails to be independent.

---

You may use $f_{Z_1,Z_2,Z_3}(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ to find the pairwise joint pdfs; and even use those to find the marginals.

$$\begin{align}f_{Z_1,Z_2}(z_1,z_2) &= \int_0^1 f_{Z_1,Z_2,Z_3}(z_1,z_2,s)\,\mathrm d s\\[2ex]f_{Z_1,Z_3}(z_1,z_3) &= \int_0^1 f_{Z_1,Z_2,Z_3}(z_1,s,z_3)\,\mathrm d s\\[2ex]f_{Z_2,Z_3}(z_2,z_3) &= \int_0^1 f_{Z_1,Z_2,Z_3}(s,z_2,z_3)\,\mathrm d s\\[2ex]f_{Z_1}(z_1) &= \int_0^1 f_{Z_1,Z_2}(z_1,s)\,\mathrm d s\\[2ex]f_{Z_2}(z_2) &= \int_0^1 f_{Z_1,Z_2}(s,z_2)\,\mathrm d s\\[2ex]f_{Z_3}(z_3) &= \int_0^1 f_{Z_2,Z_3}(s,z_3)\,\mathrm d s\end{align}$$